# Grouping parent categories into sections

Tags: categories, taxonomy, navigation, groupby

I have the following post categories:

- Personal Care
- Jewelry
- Health & Fitness
- Automotive
- Gadgets
- Health & Fitness

and have two sections: Men and Women, what I'm trying to do is to group the above categories into their respective sections.

My menu would be like:

- Men Section

  - Automotive
  - Gadgets
  - Health & Fitness
- Women Section

  - Personal Care
  - Jewelry
  - Health & Fitness

Also, there are categories that appear on both sections (e.g. health & fitness).

I understand I could use parent-child categories for this, but the sections are just for menu grouping only and should not appear in the permalink or breadcrumbs. Is this possible?

I'm currently looking at custom taxonomies but not sure if I need it. 
So I would really like some input on the right approach for doing this.

**Update:**

I found a good example of what I intend to achieve: http://www.catalogs.com/

Clicking on the Health and Fitness link under For Men and For Women top links will send you to the same page listing all posts under health & fitness.

That is pretty much how I want to present it, I just haven't figured out how to translate it into wordpress.

Comment: Use WordPress menu, Create custom link menu item with `#` as link and Label them with group names.

Comment: If you need to list posts under your "Section" you are not talking only about menu, you need parent-child category relationship or custom queries to create that list of posts. Also, can you explain the difference betwen "Section > Category" and "Category > child category"? There is no difference for me.

Comment: Updated my question and added a link to a site that pretty much does what I intend to do.

If I use parent-child categories, I will have duplicate categories if it appears on multiple parents. I just want to group the parent categories.

@Sisir - will check out the menu